# How to set default alias on cloudControl

Tags: alias, cloudcontrol

I have a cloudControl app and have added `TXT` and `CNAME` entries for the alias settings in order to make the app available under my own domain. Now when I make a

```
$ cctrlapp myapp/default alias
```

on my app, I get something like

```
Aliases
    name                                   default  verified
    myapp.cloudcontrolapp.com                  1        1
    myapp.cloudcontrolled.com                  1        1
    www.myapp.com                              0        1
```

How can I unset default for the first two entries and set default for my own domain?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The default entries on the Alias are output are the platform domains, which are provided automatically and exist for every deployment. So this can not be changed.
From the perspective of the routing tier all aliases are the same and there is no difference between default and non-default entries.

Do you have issues using your domain?